# Insert Bean into list at certain point

Tags: java

I've got a list of beans and I'm checking to see if in that list there are at least 2 beans with the getter that returns "VALUEA" and "VALUEB". This is so I can build a "total" bean just for them two called "VALUEC TOTAL". I'm also making a "grand total" bean row at the very end.

My issue here is just the "VALUEC TOTAL". I need to add that bean to the list after "VALUEB" in the original list instead of how I'm doing it at the very end.

I can confirm that summary is not empty.

```
summary = new ArrayList<WorkoutPlanBean>();
beans = dao.getAppropriationSummaryBySor(criteria, summary);

//Here we are setting up lists to be used to be added to the bottom of "Rollup" as "Totals" 
List<WorkoutPlanBean> valuecList = new ArrayList<WorkoutPlanBean>();
List<WorkoutPlanBean> sumList = new ArrayList<WorkoutPlanBean>();
for (WorkoutPlanBean b: summary)
{
    //We need 2 beans...one with VALUEA and one with VALUEB
    if( b.getSor().getShortName().equals("VALUEA") || b.getSor().getShortName().equals("VALUEB"))
    {
        valuecList.add(b);
    }
    sumList.add(b);
}
// Create VALUEC totals bean.
if (valuecList.size() > 1 )
{
    WorkoutPlanBean valuecTotals = new WorkoutPlanBean();
    valuecTotals.setSor(VALUEC_TOTALS_SOR);

    for (WorkoutPlanBean bean : valuecList)
    {
        valuecTotals.setQuantity(Overview.totalsIntegerAdd(valuecTotals.getQuantity(),
                                 bean.getQuantity()));

        valuecTotals.setHours(Overview.totalsDoubleAdd(valuecTotals.getHours(),
                              bean.getHours()));

        valuecTotals.setValue(Overview.totalsBigDecimalAdd(valuecTotals.getValue(),
                              bean.getValue()));
     }
     summary.add(valuecTotals); 
 }

 // Create Totals bean.
 if (sumList.size() > 1 )
 {
     WorkoutPlanBean globalTotals = new WorkoutPlanBean();
     globalTotals.setSor(GRAND_TOTALS_SOR);

     for (WorkoutPlanBean bean : sumList)
     {
         globalTotals.setQuantity(Overview.totalsIntegerAdd(globalTotals.getQuantity(),
                                  bean.getQuantity()));
         globalTotals.setHours(Overview.totalsDoubleAdd(globalTotals.getHours(),
                               bean.getHours()));
         globalTotals.setValue(Overview.totalsBigDecimalAdd(globalTotals.getValue(),
                               bean.getValue()));
     }
     summary.add(globalTotals); 
 }

 request.setAttribute("summary", summary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate in your list using an index rather than a for-each loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < summary.size(); i++){
    WorkoutPlanBean b = summary.get(i);
    ...
}
```

So you could remember the index of your last VALUEA/VALUEB, then you could summary.add(index, element) your sum...

Anyway have a look at the [ArrayList Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

And BTW you could also calculate both totals during this first loop, with no need for valuecList and sumList...

here is an example just editing your code so maybe you'll have to correct some typos:

```
summary = new ArrayList<WorkoutPlanBean>();
    beans = dao.getAppropriationSummaryBySor(criteria, summary);

    WorkoutPlanBean valuecTotals = new WorkoutPlanBean();
    valuecTotals.setSor(VALUEC_TOTALS_SOR);

    WorkoutPlanBean globalTotals = new WorkoutPlanBean();
    globalTotals.setSor(GRAND_TOTALS_SOR);

    int nbMdmc = 0; // to count VALUEA & VALUEB to know if a total is needed
    int lastMdmcIndex = 0;

    for (int i=0; i< summary.size(); i++)
    {
        WorkoutPlanBean bean = summary.get(i);

        //We need 2 beans...one with VALUEA and one with VALUEB
        if( bean.getSor().getShortName().equals("VALUEA") || bean.getSor().getShortName().equals("VALUEB"))
        {
            lastMdmcIndex = i;
            // count VALUEA and VALUEB
            nbMdmc++;

            // add to valuec total
            valuecTotals.setQuantity(Overview.totalsIntegerAdd(valuecTotals.getQuantity(),
                                                               bean.getQuantity()));
            valuecTotals.setHours(Overview.totalsDoubleAdd(valuecTotals.getHours(),
                                                                bean.getHours()));
            valuecTotals.setValue(Overview.totalsBigDecimalAdd(valuecTotals.getValue(),
                                                                bean.getValue()));
        }

        // add to grand total
        globalTotals.setQuantity(Overview.totalsIntegerAdd(globalTotals.getQuantity(),
                                                               bean.getQuantity()));
        globalTotals.setHours(Overview.totalsDoubleAdd(globalTotals.getHours(),
                                                                bean.getHours()));
        globalTotals.setValue(Overview.totalsBigDecimalAdd(globalTotals.getValue(),
                                                                bean.getValue()));

    }

    if(nbMdmc > 1) summary.add(lastMdmcIndex+1, valuecTotals); 

    if(summary.size() > 1) summary.add(globalTotals); 


request.setAttribute("summary", summary);
```

Comment: Thanks...but Im not that clever to see where I can do the totals in the first loop....

Comment: @DocHoliday: I've edited my answer (I just had to rearrange your code to do everything in one loop)...

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the needed index and use:
 `list.add(index, yourBean)`